# How can I collapse probes to single value per gene using GEOquery?

Tags: r, microarray, gene-expression, geoquery

I have extracted microarray gene expression data from GEO using the `GEOquery` package in R. There are multiple probes per gene. Is there a way to select the best probe? If so, what would be the criteria and how can you do this? Maybe use [Jetset probes](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-12-474) (=best quality probes) for this?

Otherwise, would you use the average expression value of all probes for each gene? If so, how can you do this in R, please?

**EDIT**

Edit after comment below:
I like the suggestion proposed here: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/70133/, using this code:

```
 Probesets=paste("a",1:200,sep="") # "fake probesets"
 Genes=sample(letters,200,replace=T)
 Value=rnorm(200)
 X=data.frame(Probesets,Genes,Value) # I edited this line, as it seemed to contain an error
 X=X[order(X$Value,decreasing=T),]
 Y=X[which(!duplicated(X$Genes)),]
```

But, I do not understand it. How is the value for each gene in Y calculated? It was commented that this is the MAD, but calculating the Median Absolute Deviation (MAD) by hand results in a different value. Could anyone help, please? Thank you.

Comment: The post: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/3082/duplicate-gene-symbol-handling-in-geo-gene-expression-data/3083#3083 helped a little bit, but did not answer all my questions.

Comment: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/92128/

Comment: Thank you. Lots of options! I still have a question. See edit above. Thank you.

Comment: The trick is `duplicated()` being used with `!` and only after sorting `X` in decreasing order. Basically, you sort your "values" from higher to lower and `duplicated()` gives you FALSE if that particular "value" was never observed in the "array of interest". When you negate this with `!`, you only keep the first occurence of a particular value and this first occurence would be the highest as it was sorted already in the previous step.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is very clear now. Now I am only left with figuring out how to calculate the MAD in R, but I will search for that.